# d3js - Column Graph - data point alignment

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

[image: Vertical/Column Bar Graph]
This is a chart that I have made using d3.js. I want my bars to be centered around the tick values - as in the middle bar of each set (of 3 bars) should coincide with the month name. Is there some way to do this elegantly? Do let me know if you need more info on the data set or the chart functions.

Some helpful code

```
this.container.selectAll('g.container')
    .data(this.data)
  .enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'container')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i){
        console.log(d.dimension, this)
        var x = self.margin.left + self.xScale(d.dimension.value);
        var y = self.margin.top;
        return 'translate('+ x + ',' + y +')'
});

this.bars = this.container.selectAll('g.container')
    .selectAll('rect.bar')
    .data(function(d){ return d; })
  .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('width', 3)
    .attr('height', function(d){
        console.log(d.y, d.key, this);
        return availableHeight - self.yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){ return self.yScale(d.y); })
    .attr('x', function(d, i){ return i * 5 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting either the `transform` of the `g.container` or the `x` attribute of the appended rectangles. I would adjust the transforms, i.e. change

```
.attr('transform', function(d, i){
  console.log(d.dimension, this)
  return 'translate('+ 
          (self.margin.left + self.xScale(d.dimension.value)) + ',' 
          + self.margin.top +')'
});
```

to include some extra space (half the difference between the `dimension.value`s).

Comment: how do I figure out this difference? If i could find out the values at which my ticks are positioned, I could simply use that

Comment: You simply calculate the difference between two consecutive `dimension.value`. Presumably this is something in your JSON?